# django sekizai {% addtoblock %} tag is not working properly

Tags: django, django-templates, django-sekizai

I'm trying to implement django sekizai app. It is duplicating the js files that i'm adding.

base template:

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}
...
{% render_block "my_js" %}
```

template that is using this base:

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}
<div id="a1" >
    {% addtoblock "my_js" %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/my_js.js"></script>
    {% endaddtoblock %}
</div>
{% addtoblock "my_js" %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/my_js.js"></script>
{% endaddtoblock %}
```

Now here the rendered template has  rendered twice.But when I tried adding the same script within the div it wasn't duplicated. Would appreciate if someone can shed some light on this!

Also when i try to use {% addtoblock %} in a template rendered by a template tag the script goes missing (It is neither included nor it stays in that template).

Note: The template tags, `render_block` and `addtoblock`, are from the [django-sekizai](http://django-sekizai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) package.

Comment: well i could find the reason behind the duplication of my script which is the difference in the indentation of the script within and outside the div. {% addtoblock %} tag apparently doesn't remove the white-spaces. So the solution to my first question is a silly one as below:

    {% load sekizai_tags %}
    <div id="a1" >
    {% addtoblock "my_js" %}<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/my_js.js"></script>{% endaddtoblock %}
    </div>
    {% addtoblock "my_js" %}<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/my_js.js"></script>{% endaddtoblock %}

Comment: Also in custom template tag's template the scripts were disappearing. As per [django-sekizai-docs](https://github.com/ojii/django-sekizai/blob/master/docs/restrictions.rst) it is compulsory to use either SekizaiContext or RequestContext and the sekizai context processor but i found a workaround if you want to size down your template's context(say cont={}) use this cont['SEKIZAI_CONTENT_HOLDER'] = context['SEKIZAI_CONTENT_HOLDER']. With this workaround you need not use RequestContext and only sekezai context processor would be enough.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`{% addtoblock %}` and `{% endaddtoblock %}` have to be inside of a block in templates that inherit another template.

```
# base.html
<html>
    ...
    {% render_block 'js' %}
    {% block js %}{% endblock %}
</html>


# some-page.html
{% inherits 'base.html' %}

{% block js %}
    {% addtoblock 'js' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" ... />
    {% endaddtoblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: It will not work. the sekizai will parse it as "\n(8 spaces)<script type="text/javascript" ... />" and not "<script type="text/javascript" ... />".

Comment: That works for me. I'm not sure what might be going on with the newline character and spaces, but I've used the same code I posted on at least 10 projects that all work as expected. Perhaps there's something else altering the output?

Comment: Yep, this fixed it up. But *why* is this the case? I presume it's a limitation of Django's template system?

Comment: I'm not certain, I was just following the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

{% addtoblock %} inside the template (*something.html*) from an **inclusion tag**:

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('something.html', takes_context=True)
def render_something(context, some_arg):
    sezikai_ctx_var = getattr(settings, 'SEKIZAI_VARNAME', 'SEKIZAI_CONTENT_HOLDER')
    attrs = {
        'some_arg': some_arg,
        sezikai_ctx_var: context[sezikai_ctx_var]
    }
    return attrs
```

Comment: Very useful - is this documented anywhere?